# Item Validation error message customization

Tags: validation-list-items

I have a question regarding SharePoint item validation. Is there a way to customize how the error message from item validation is rendered? For example, to apply some CSS, or to alter it's placement on the page? I have researched this but cannot seem to find an answer on how to do this while keeping item validation? I know forms can be customized and we can use CSR validation, but that then bypasses if a user decides to use Quick Edit.

Any help or a direction would be very appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint have built-in validation ability. In your library or list, click on library settings or list settings -> click on the column you need  -> click **Column Validation**. Here you can input your validation formula and user message.

By search **column validation** you should able to find lots reference and [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/examples-of-common-formulas-in-sharepoint-lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3) is one from Microsoft.

By using column validation the rule apply on various views as well as API.